# Gmail filtering attachments without a file extension

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

How can I make a Gmail filter to respond to any messages with attachments that have no filetype?

`filetype:none` doesn't work for me, because it searches for files with extension `.none`.

Comment: Is filetype even an available search option?

Comment: Have you tried -filetype? (just a minus before "filetype")